# Custom element with position absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position, custom-element, fin-hypergrid

I am trying to contain/put a `fin-hypergrid` within a web component, but because it's scrollbars are custom `div`s with `position: absolute` on them, they are positioned absolute to the `window` rather that the component itself.

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50kyyfam/

I'm almost certain I need to add a css properties to the `:host` style to tell the grid to position absolute to the boundary of the `data-grid` component, but I don't know what it should be?

**EDIT**: As a side note, if any of the `fin-hypergrid` are looking, the minified version of core threw an exception when initialising the above jsfiddle. (Chrome 63)

Comment: To position an *absolutely positioned* element *relative* to its containing element, `position: relative` should be declared on that containing element, e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/50kyyfam/1/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError - awesome, I just added `position: relative` to the `:host` style and it worked as expected - if you create answer, I can mark it as correct

Comment: Would be happy to, allow me a few minutes and I'll have one posted.

Comment: Two down votes...is there something wrong with my question?...have I broken some sort of etiquette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To position an *absolutely positioned* element *relative* to its containing element, `position: relative` should be declared on that containing element, e.g:

```
data-grid {
    position: relative;
}
```

```js
class DataGrid extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.createShadowRoot().innerHTML = `
       <style>
         :host {
           display: block;
          }
          
          div {
           height: 100%;
           width: 100%;
          }
        </style>
        <div></div>
      `;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
   const grid = new fin.Hypergrid(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('div'));
      const data = [
        { name: 'Company 1', price: 300 },
        { name: 'Company 2', price: 200 },
        { name: 'Company 3', price: 150 },
        { name: 'Company 4', price: 500 },
        { name: 'Company 5', price: 999 }
      ];
      grid.setData(data);
    }

  }

  customElements.define('data-grid', DataGrid);
```

```css
data-grid {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://fin-hypergrid.github.io/core/2.0.2/build/fin-hypergrid.js"></script>

<data-grid style="width:100px; height: 150px;"></data-grid>
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50kyyfam/1/)

**To expand upon**, for the sake of clarity and for the potential benefit of any other possible readers:

- When declaring an element as an *absolutely positioned* element
  (`absolute` or `fixed`) you are *removing the element from the
  natural document flow*; which simply means the element is no longer
  interacting with sibling elements in the way `relative` or `static`
  elements do (imagine the element "siting above" the rest of the DOM).
- By default, an *absolutely positioned* element's position is
  "relative" to the *window*; this means if you offset its position
  with `left` or `right` property values it'll move a distance equal to
  the property value *from the window*. You can position an element
  with a `position` property value of `absolute` (not `fixed`) relative
  to any containing element *if you declare relative positioning to
  that containing element*.